# How can I auto selct a List item from UL?

Tags: javascript

[CLick here to see image!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Amuf3.png)

I want to auto click the list item new with the console imput in CHrome ->look image.

I dont know how to do it. Does Anybody has an idea?

I tried the following code but it didnt work:

```
document.getElementbyId("new-category").click();
```

Comment: Please read the [help] before posting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use jQuery to trigger the click event by using the below code. See image from this link
http://prntscr.com/m0b5wz

```
$( "#new-category" ).trigger( "click" );
```

note: must add jquery first by pasting the all the code from this below google js to your console and then add the trigger event
https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js

Comment: thank you that hepled me a lot. As you can see it is like a menu. But it doesnt open the webpage with the "new" items. It just selects it

Comment: I noticed that you have a debugger mode on this site due to which it is blocking the link to open moreover always make sure you write your entire Javascript code like this
 $( document ).ready(function() {

//your javascript code here

}

Comment: sometimes DOM isn't loaded completely and hence it cannot find all the ID's

Answer (score 0):

Can you try below code on console ?

```
document.getElementById('new-category').click()
```

To add event listeners use below something code

```
document.getElementById('new-category').addEventListener("click", function(){
  document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = "Hello World";
});
```

Comment: We are just selecting and firing the click command. To set the what action happens, please use event listners.